# how to make Javascript keyboard shortcut in all browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I'm trying to make shortcut with javascript. It works with FF but not with IE8.
I'm using this code -

```
document.onkeydown=function(e)
{ 

if(e.which == 83) 

{ alert("hello"); } 
}
```

Please give me a simple code which will support all browsers. 
Thanks

Comment: [Read this.](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make your code cross-browser, you should:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) { 
  e = e || window.event;
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

  if(keyCode == 83) { alert("hello"); }
}
```

Check the above snippet [here](http://jsbin.com/igote).

Comment: It works. I was really looking something like that.

Thank you very very much. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you permitted to use jQuery?  Because this will work:

```
$(window).keydown(function(event){
     if(event.keyCode == 83){
          alert('hello');
     } 
});
```

[Partially boosted from here](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keydown#fn)

Comment: Thank you, But I don't like to use jQuery.